# Toast not working,App stops when toast is to be displayed

Tags: android, toast

I have created a small application to check whether the password entered by user is valid or not. it is being able to check , but its not displaying the toast and as soon as i click the button , it shows "Unfortunately , your app has stopped working". I am using my device for deployment. Please help me find out , why the toast is not working. I have used a command which sets the value of variable a,b,c in the edit text field , to check whether it is coming correct. And yes it was coming correct. So the problem lies in the toast as per i think.

```
public class second extends AppCompatActivity {

    public EditText fname ;
    public EditText lname ;
    public EditText email ;
    public EditText pass ;
    public EditText blood;
    public EditText cpass;
    public EditText add ;
    public EditText mob ;
    public Toast t ;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
        fname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fname);
        lname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lname);
        email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pass);
        add = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.add);
        cpass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cpass);
        mob = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mob);
        blood = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.blood);
        Button sign = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sign);

        sign.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String sfname = fname.getText().toString();
                String spass = pass.getText().toString();
                String scpass = cpass.getText().toString();
                validate(spass, scpass);
            }
        });
    }
        public void validate(String spass ,String scpass){
        int a =0;
        int b =0;
        int c =0;
          t = new Toast(this);
        int len = spass.length();
        for(int i =0;i<len;i++){
            char d = spass.charAt(i);
            if(d>=48 && d<=57){
                a++;
            }
            if(d>=65 && d<=90){
                b++;
            }
            if(d>=33 && d<=47){
                c++;
            }
        }
        email.setText(a+" "+b+" "+c);

        if(a==0 || b==0 || c==0){
            t.makeText(this, "Password should contain atleast one special character , one capital letter and one number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            t.show();

        } else {
            if(spass.equals(scpass)){
                t.makeText(this,"login succesful",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                t.show();
            } else {
                t.makeText(this,"passwords dont match",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }

    }
    }
```

Comment: here t = new Toast(this); instead of "this" write getApplicationContext(), also in your toast.

Comment: creating instance of Toast you have to use simply Toast();
.makeText(this, "string value", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: you need to pass context for the Toast toast = new Toast(context);

Comment: Please see: [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
toast.show()
```

or

```
Toast.makeText(context, text, duration).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#Toast(android.content.Context)), it says

> Toast (Context context) Construct an empty Toast object. You must call
>   setView(View) before you can call show().

So when you create `Toast` object from its constructor, it is considered that you are trying to create `Custom Toast`

If you are not creating any, then use like:

```
public Toast t;    // Global variable
```

Now inside your `validate` method:

```
t = Toast.makeText(this, "Password should contain atleast one special character , one capital letter and one number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
t.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes to you method , try using this one .
You can find more details on https://stackoverflow.com/a/21963343

```
public void validate(String spass ,String scpass){
    int a =0;
    int b =0;
    int c =0;
//        Toast t = new Toast(this);
    int len = spass.length();
    for(int i =0;i<len;i++){
        char d = spass.charAt(i);
        if(d>=48 && d<=57){
            a++;
        }
        if(d>=65 && d<=90){
            b++;
        }
        if(d>=33 && d<=47){
            c++;
        }
    }
    email.setText(a+" "+b+" "+c);

    if(a==0 || b==0 || c==0){

        /*
        * updated
        * */
        Toast.makeText(this, "Password should contain atleast one special character , one capital letter and one number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    } else {
        if(spass.equals(scpass)){
            /*Updated*/
            Toast.makeText(this,"login succesful",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            /*Updated*/
            Toast.makeText(this,"passwords dont match",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }

}
```